# Opening NetworkX Viewer from an existing Tkinter window

Tags: python, graph, tkinter, networkx, tkinter-canvas

I have a sample application which contains a main window with a simple button "Draw Graph in a new window". On clicking this button, it should take me to a child window and draw a graph there. Instead, the graph is drawn in the main window, NetworkX viewer is opened in a new (third) window and the child window is blank.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import networkx as nx
from networkx_viewer import Viewer

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
counter = 0
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Draw Graph in a new window", 
                            command=self.create_window)
    self.button.pack(side="top")

def create_window(self):
    self.counter += 1
    t = tk.Toplevel(self)
    t.wm_title("Window #%s" % self.counter)
    l = tk.Label(t, text="This is window #%s" % self.counter)
    l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

    G=nx.complete_graph(30)
    G.add_edge('a','b')
    G.add_edge('b','c')
    G.add_edge('c','a')
    G.add_edge('c','d')
    G.add_edge('b','d')


    G.add_edge('p','q')
    G.add_edge('q','r')
    G.add_edge('r','p')
    G.add_edge('r','s')
    G.add_edge('q','s')

    G.add_edge('w','x')
    G.add_edge('x','y')
    G.add_edge('y','w')
    G.add_edge('y','z')
    G.add_edge('x','z')        

    app = Viewer(G)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
 root = tk.Tk()
 main = MainWindow(root)
 main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
 root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before and it is befuddling. It's not been directly resolved, but if you really need to use tkinter to have a separate parent GUI, the only fix I've seen is to use another displaying solution. Matplotlib's pyplot works well with networkx, and a tkinter menu can spawn the display with no issues.